# Generate jwt when registering user using djangorestfrfamework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

Hi i'm playing with `django` and `djangorestframework-simplejwt` and wrote a simple app to register users. Now it seems from reading the documentation and searching online the only way of generating a token is by passing the username, and password to the url `url(r'^api/token/$', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')`. So it seems i have to create the user first and upon successfully creating the user then send the username, and password again to the url to generate a token. But i want to be able to create a token when the user is created and not have to resend the username and password after user is created. Is there an easier away to generate a jwt when registering a user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that with RefreshToken.
Here is how...

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.utils.six import text_type

def somewhere_in_signup_view:
    ...
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    tokens = {
        'refresh_token': text_type(refresh),
        'access_token': text_type(refresh.access_token),
    }
    ...
```